# Is Stormcrawler v1.14 compatible with Elasticsearch 6.7.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

In the completed tasks list for Stormcrawler 1.14 I see both "Upgrade to Elasticsearch 7.0.x" and "ES 6.70 dependency elasticsearch" listed. Does that mean that 1.14 is compatible with both?

I ask this mostly because I was attempting to use `mvn archetype:generate` to generate a 1.13 stormcrawler, and got the message: `Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler:storm-crawler-archetype:1.14] found in catalog remote`.  We are on ES 6.7.1 so I am wondering if 1.14 is compatible or if I need to somehow manually load 1.13.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, StormCrawler 1.14 is not compatible with Elasticsearch 6.7. I've even tried to access an 6.7 index with StormCrawler 1.14 - it does not work, at least not with the status index. There has been an upgrade to 6.7 during the development on 1.14, the upgrade to 7.0 happened shortly before the release of 1.14.

Comment: The decision to move to ES7 was based on the following consultation https://twitter.com/stormcrawlerapi/status/1124259162039422977

Comment: @JulienNioche - is their a reason that I cannot use `mvn archetype:generate` to generate a 1.13 stormcrawler? I can do 1.12 or 1.14, but not 1.13...

Comment: @jimmat have tried and it works. Getting 
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler:storm-crawler-archetype:1.14] found in catalog remote